# Is it conventional to provide a list of GUI element descriptions in a thesis?

Tags: thesis, computer-science, graphics, stem, glossary

I'm currently writing my dissertation/thesis regarding my Rubik's Cube Solver program (sounds more exciting than it actually is haha). Anyway, I have created a GUI to visualize and animate the cube throughout various processes like solving and scrambling. However, this GUI has more elements such as buttons, sliders, multi-dropdown lists, etc. than I originally thought.

Would it be convenient to provide each specific GUI element with its own description somewhere? E.g. a glossary for the GUI or perhaps bullet-pointed? I had a recent thought of labeling everything via a screenshot?

I get this could be subjective but what would be regarded as a more professional/cleaner route to take?

Any thoughts, ideas, recommendations are more than welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are writing a thesis, not a user manual for a program. Focus on the technical advances. That is what your thesis will be judged on.

I'd suggest leaving the GUI out of it unless you have designed new, and innovative, human-computer interaction elements. Creating such elements has value, certainly, but it doesn't sound like that is the focus of your work.

If you want a user manual, make that a separate project - just for fun.

Comment: I find this fascinating. Is this an undergraduate thesis project? What did your advisor recommend? If this is PhD level @Buffy is giving you the best advice in this situation. Crank out an online user guide, keep your software versioned and maintained, point to it in your thesis, but otherwise focus on your intellectual contribution.

Comment: Hi there. This is an undergrad thesis. My advisor has chosen this time period to be on holiday so I have been especially active on the stack exchange among other places, lol. I'm not too aware of too much conventionality regarding versions... but I have been keeping my github repo up to date with what I'm doing.